# Excel VBA Do until Column E

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code for copying Range(D9:E31) with all the formatting and borders, also merged cells (D9:E9). Once user is pressing button Range(D9:E31) is copied to next available cells Range(F9:G31), Range(H9:I31) etc.

I have developed a code for deleting copied cells in reverse order Range(H9:31), Range(F9:G31)... However my core data is located in Range(D9:E31) so it should not be deleted in any circumstances.

How to make my code run until Column E. Once it reaches Column E it should stop working and button should do nothing no matter how many times it is pressed. I can add warning message myself later.

I have tried `Do Until` with no success. However I do not need to loop until Column E. I need to run VBA each time I press the button. By using loop it will delete everything until Column E? Maybe in this case `If` should be used? If next cell is not in Column E then run the code?

My code:

```
        Sub Remove()
    With Worksheets("Price calculation")
'Do Until Columns(4)
        lc = .Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Range(.Cells(9, lc - 0), .Cells(9, lc)).MergeArea.UnMerge
        lc = .Cells(11, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Range(.Cells(9, lc - 1), .Cells(31, lc)).ClearContents
        .Range(.Cells(9, lc - 1), .Cells(31, lc)).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        .Range(.Cells(9, lc - 1), .Cells(31, lc)).Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## ClearContents of Merged Columns

Since it is unclear if you want to delete all or one by one I've included both.

### One-By-One

Every time you run this, the last 2-column range is 'removed', if any.

```
Sub RemoveOneByOne()
    Dim lc As Integer
    With Worksheets("Price calculation")
        lc = .Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        If lc > 5 Then
            With .Range(.Cells(9, lc - 1), .Cells(31, lc))
                .UnMerge
                .ClearContents
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 2
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

### All

Every time you run this, all 2-column ranges are 'removed', if any.

```
Sub RemoveAll()
    Dim lc As Integer
    With Worksheets("Price calculation")
        lc = .Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        With .Range(.Cells(9, 6), .Cells(31, lc))
            .UnMerge
            .ClearContents
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Sub Remove()


    With Worksheets("Price calculation")
    'Do Until Columns(4)
        Do
            lc = .Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            If lc <= 4 Then Exit Do

            .Range(.Cells(9, lc - 0), .Cells(9, lc)).MergeArea.UnMerge
            lc = .Cells(11, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Range(.Cells(9, lc - 1), .Cells(31, lc)).ClearContents
            .Range(.Cells(9, lc - 1), .Cells(31, lc)).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            .Range(.Cells(9, lc - 1), .Cells(31, lc)).Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, however I need to run code each time I press the button (not delete everything until Column E by one click). Searching for solution the whole day =)

Comment: @user7202022,  Delete  do  loop

Answer (score 2):

You forgot about **Loop** word at the end of the loop.

```
Do Until condition
    [ statements ]
    [ Exit Do ]
    [ statements ]
Loop

Do
    [ statements ]
    [ Exit Do ]
    [ statements ]
Loop Until condition
```

For your situation:

```
sub deleteCol()
    dim i as long
    i = 100 'index of last column, which u want to delete
    do until i = 4
        columns(i).delete
    loop 
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! How do I set `Do Until condition` to do until 4:th E Column?

Comment: i = 100 

        Do Until i = 4
                Columns(i).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

        i = i-1 Loop

Comment: Where i is an index of your last column, which you want to delete

Answer (score 1):

The below provide some guidelines how to loop until column E.The code loop columns and import he value Test from column A to column E.

```
Option Explicit

    Sub test()

        Dim i As Long

        i = 1

        Do Until i = 6
            Sheet1.Cells(1, i).Value = "Test"

        i = i + 1

        Loop

    End Sub
```